# How to attach job's output to the notification e-mail in Databricks?

Tags: databricks, monitoring

Is there a way to attach the notebook output to the e-mail notification sent after the job run?

And if it's not possible, what would be the best way to automate exporting these outputs?

Comment: Natively, I do not see any options available. Check this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/job-notifications.html) for integrations with slack and others and [aws-email](https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/kb/notebooks/send-email-aws.html) for sending email via AWS SES. You can search around for several posts on how to send email using Python here in SO itself.